# HTML field validation, pattern attribute

Tags: html, validation, design-patterns, zipcode

I don't know what the bold part means:

`<input name="zip_code" type="text" pattern="\d{5}(-\d{4})?" required="required" />`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: 5 digits then a `-` followed by 4 other digits, which is grouped eg. `12345-6789`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/YLwcDv/2/

Answer (score 0):

`\d{5}` means that 5 digits are required and
`(-\d{4})?` means that the character "-" and 4 other digits are optional

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern="\d{5}(-\d{4})?"
```

Means

1. Starts with 5 digits
2. Followed by a dash (optional)
3. Followed by 4 digits (optional)

Example

```
48412 - Accepted
4488 - Rejected
44775-4412 - Accepted
74547-45745 - Rejected
```

Rules are as follows

```
^       a string that starts with...
(       either
  \d    a digit (0-9)...
  {4}   that repeats four times...
|       or
  \d    a digit (0-9)...
  {6}   that repeats six times...
)
$ and then ends
```